# Flex box add BG/IMG behind IMG

Tags: css, flexbox, styles

I want to add an effect in bottom of my Image.

This could be done by creating background or as I'm trying adding another Image behind.

Markup

```
<div class="a">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <img class="imgA1" src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
    <img class="imgB1" src="http://placehold.it/200x200/ff0000">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 .container {display: flex; position:relative; justify-content: center;     align-items: center;}
 h2 {position:absolute; z-index: 2;}
 .imgA1 { position:absolute; top: 8px; left: 0px; } 
 .imgB1 { position:relative; bottom: 0px; left:  0px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/62c8zxjh/

Background would have different color and would work as an shadow to the image.

I want to align the H2, imgA1, imgA2 in middle responsively.

When I get BG/IMG behind the main IMG, if I zoom in or test responsively it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without an image showing your desired outcome this is more of a guess but is this what you mean?

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.container img {
  width: 100%;
}
.imgA1 {
  position: absolute;
  top:8px;
}
.content-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="imgA1" src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
  <img class="imgB1" src="http://placehold.it/200x200/ff0000">
  <div class="content-container">
    <h2>
      Title
    </h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yap, that is exactly what I was trying, will review your code and learn from it, thanks!